# Secure database storage in Android

Tags: java, android, security

I'm implementing the in-app-billing system for my app and (as the documentation advices) I'd like to add some encryption system to the database.

I've tested [SQLCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/), I liked it but since it need to override all the classes at `android.database.sqlite.*` your app loses the connection to that part of the SDK, losing possible important future updates and depending on the developer (or yourself since is opensource).

Other solution I've considered is to add a extra column in the `sensible` tables storing there a value (unique for each device), and then ignore the data that don't contain that key. But this method is clearly more weak.

How can I improve the security without using SQLCipher? Thanks

Comment: why don't you just encrypt the database file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `sensible` table contains columns that are sensible and some that aren't, and if you don't use the sensible columns in a `where` clause, the you can easly encrypt/decrypt just that sensible fields on write/read operations without a significant performance cost.

If you need to use sensible columns in your where clause in a table with just a few records, you can read all the records, decrypt and choose.

If none of the above aplies, then I have no other suggestion beside `SQLCipher`.

Comment: After having a second thought, I realise that it works even when using sensible columns on `where` clause, as long as you also encrypt the value you want to compare with. The real limitation is with the `sort by` clause, as there is no way to know how to sort encrypted records without decrypt them first.